# Play! Framework: how to promote an entity from a parent class to be a child class

Tags: hibernate, playframework

Suppose I have a system that makes an audit on user actions:
like a user called XXX made a cup of tea, and then made ..., then made ...

so there is a table with UserActions (userId, actionId)

now the user is married and -on my system- now he can have children so I want to promote the normal user entity to a married user entity who can have a list of children (other normal user entities)

like:
concrete parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends Model {
}
```

concrete child entity:

```
@Entity
public class MarriedUser extends User {
    @OneToMany()
    public List<User> children;
}
```

and my problem is that how to write the code in the controller to promote the entity in the database from a parent(User) to child(MarriedUser) - typically this is done in the database by just inserting a new record in the MarriedUser table with the same Id of the User (as I'm making the InheritanceType joined) so in the database it is simple, but the hibernate code is what I don't know.

I told u the audit piece of info because I can't just delete the user XXX and create a new marriedUser with a new id, i need it with the same id.

so please help me with the hibernate code ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are facing problems because of an abuse of inheritance.

You cannot change the type of an object without losing its object identity, therefore you shouldn't use inheritance to represent different states of the same object, as you're trying to do.

You can use separate objects to represent marital status of `User`:

```
@Entity 
public class User extends Model {
    @OneToOne
    public Marriage marriage;
    ...
}

@Entity 
public class Marriage extends Model {
    @OneToMany()
    public List<User> children; 
}
```

Alternatively, you can move `children` to `User`, and use some flag to represent marital status, if you need to.

And yes, as far as I know, there is no way to change the type of the existing entity in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are approaching your issue the wrong way. What you have here is a ['state machine'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) in which an entity (your user) can be in some states which allow/disallow certain actions.

You may have more success by declouping the state of the entity and its storage. Use an enum (or similar) to store the state and then check that the state is correct when trying to trigger an action on the Model. If it's not a valid state, raise an exception.

Your UI should limit the range of available actions as per the status code.

```
@Entity 
 public class User extends Model {

    // this status code could be an enum, or any other type that fits
    public int statusCode;

    ...

    public void action() {
        if(statusCode != 1){
          throw new IllegalStateException("State 1 required for this action");
        }
        //code for action
    }
 }
```